# How to check how many array elements have values?

Tags: java, android, arrays

How do I check how many elements have values? yes, this can also include how to check if an element has a value.

```
String[] Array = new String[50]; //initialization

Array[i] = "1"; // Array[0]

Array[] = "2"; // Array[1]
```

how can I know that 2 out of 50 elements have values?

(read about `ArrayList`. my app keeps crashing when I'm retrieving and displaying it.)

Answer (score 1):

You could check which elements aren't null:

```
long numWithValue = Arrays.stream(array).filter(Objects::nonNull).count();
```

EDIT:
If you can't use Java 8 syntax, you can always use an old fashioned loop:

```
int numWithValue = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; ++i){ 
    if (array[i] != null) {
        ++numWithValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: (Object::nonNull) :  Method references are not supported at this language level (i'm using api 15)

stream(arr) : cannot resolve symbol

Comment: @Ray I really suggest you use a newer version of the API. Regardless of this recommendation, check out my edited answer for a solution that would work for older versions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
int count=0;
for(int i=0;i<Array.length;i++)
if(!(Array[i]==null))
count++;
```

count is the number of elements that have been initialised.

Answer (score 0):

```
 long numWithValue = arr.length - Collections.frequency(Arrays.asList(arr), null);
```

try this, should be compiled for 1.5 JDK